# OnPointerEnter is not being called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, virtual-reality, gaze-buttons

I'm trying to animate the button while it is being gazed on. I have got the following code in which I Raycast from a sphere to find the button that it hits.

```
var eventDataCurrentPosition = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);
        eventDataCurrentPosition.position = screenPosition;

var results = new List<RaycastResult>();

EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(eventDataCurrentPosition, results);

foreach (var result in results)
{
     Debug.Log(result.gameObject.name);
}
```

In order to animate the button, I'm adding the following code to the button. Unfortunately, the `OnPointerEnter` or ``OnPointerExit is never being called.

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Button))]
public class InteractiveItem : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    public Image  progressImage;
    public bool   isEntered = false;
    RectTransform rt;
    Button        _button;
    float         timeElapsed;
    Image         cursor;
    float         GazeActivationTime = 5;

// Use this for initialization
void Awake()
{
    _button = GetComponent<Button>();
    rt      = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
}


void Update()
{
    if (isEntered)
    {
        timeElapsed              += Time.deltaTime;
        progressImage.fillAmount =  Mathf.Clamp(timeElapsed / GazeActivationTime, 0, 1);
        if (timeElapsed >= GazeActivationTime)
        {
            timeElapsed = 0;
            _button.onClick.Invoke();
            progressImage.fillAmount = 0;
            isEntered                = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        timeElapsed = 0;
    }
}

#region IPointerEnterHandler implementation

public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    CodelabUtils._ShowAndroidToastMessage("entered");
    isEntered = true;
}

#endregion

#region IPointerExitHandler implementation

public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    CodelabUtils._ShowAndroidToastMessage("exit");

    isEntered                = false;
    progressImage.fillAmount = 0;
}

#endregion
}
```

am I missing something ? or is there any other way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your Raycast supposed to trigger the `OnPointerEnter` on all results.

You will need to use [`ExecuteEvents.Execute`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute.html) like e.g.

```
ExecuteEvents.Execute(result.gameObject, eventDataCurrentPosition, ExecuteEvents.pointerEnterHandler);
```

And will also at some point have to invoke `pointerExitHandler`.

I would therefore store a HashSet like

```
using System.Linq;

private HashSet<GameObject> previousEnters = new HashSet<GameObject>();

...

foreach (var result in results.Select(r => r.gameObject))
{
    Debug.Log(result.name);
    ExecuteEvents.Execute(result, eventDataCurrentPosition, ExecuteEvents.pointerEnterHandler);
    // Store the item so you can later invoke exit on them
    if(!previousEnters.Contains(result)) previousEnters.Add(result);
}  

// This uses Linq in order to get only those entries from previousEnters that are not in the results
var exits = previousEnters.Except(results);
foreach(var item in exits)
{
    if(item) ExecuteEvents.Execute(item, eventDataCurrentPosition, ExecuteEvents.pointerExitHandler);
}
```

---

You might actually want to implement your own custom [`PointerInputModule`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.PointerInputModule.html).

---

#### Alternative/Example

As a starter you could also use my answer to [Using Raycast instead of Gaze Pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56645337/7111561) from a while ago where I created a script based on Steam's VR Laserpointer which allows to interact with 3D objects and UI elements.

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: Thanks for this! I could not find this ANYWHERE in the Unity docs - despite this API being 'production ready' for well over a year now. Did you figure this out by trial and error? Or are there docs from Unity somewhere that we can reference, which I failed at finding?